# How to use infinities with BC Math in php?

Tags: php, infinity, bcmath

I cannot find how to use infinities with BC Math. Let's take something like:

```
$result = echo bcdiv("1", $divider);
```

It goes all well until $divider is 0. So you make an exception:

```
if (!bccomp($divider, "0")) {
    $result = echo bcdiv("1", $divider);
}
else {
    $result = INF;
}
```

The problem is that $result gets computed as "0" in future calculations. I can set $result as an arbitrary large number, but that destroys the concept of exact calculations. Also, it will get much slower if I put a too large number in order to get accurate calculations.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: [The result of `1/0` is not infinity.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero)

Comment: It is indeterminate, but the right limit of 1/x at x=0 is infinity and it can often be used for calculations.

Comment: If that doesn't convince you, just forget the division and assume you want to assign infinity to $result. How would you do that in BC Math.

Comment: BC Math doesn't support infinity cases. It simply returns null when an operation would result in infinity or IEEE NaN.

Comment: So no other way than $result = "999999999*snip*9999999"?

Comment: Or just `str_repeat('9', 1000);`